# How do I filter on year in a query that has a left join?

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am trying to filter on the year 2022 in my query and it is not filtering on just 2022. I currently have the year filter in the bottom portion of my query I am thinking the where clause needs to be before the joins. I have also tried moving the where clause after the "from tp.load l" and that does not work either. I know that it is that table that I am trying to filter that year on.

```
select 
l.truck_id,
l.CREATED_DATE,
st.location_name,
st.location_address_1,
st.location_city,
st.location_state_code,
st.location_postal_code,
l.mode_type,
li.weight,
li.hazmat,
li.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION


from tp.table l

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(Select m.* from
(SELECT truck_ID,hazmat,sum(weight) as 'Weight', product_description,
Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY truck_ID ORDER BY freight_ID DESC) AS R_NO
FROM [TP].[table2] where status='active'
GROUP BY truck_ID,HAZMAT, PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,FREIGHT_ID)
m where R_NO=1)li
ON L.truck_ID=li.truck_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(Select n.* from
(SELECT truck_ID, location_name, location_address_1, location_city, location_state_code,location_postal_code, 
Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY truck_ID ORDER BY stop_ID DESC) AS R_NO
FROM [TP].[table3] where status='active' and STOP_SEQUENCE_NUMBER = '1') n where R_NO=1) st
ON L.truck_ID=st.truck_id


where year(created_datetime)= '2022'
and LOCATION_address_1 LIKE '%6210 GLENWAY%'
or LOCATION_address_1  like '%480 WILEY%'
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: AND goes before OR. You need parentheses.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this more? I currently have AND before OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where year(created_datetime)= '2022'
and LOCATION_address_1 LIKE '%6210 GLENWAY%'
or LOCATION_address_1  like '%480 WILEY%'
```

is evaluated as

```
where (year(created_datetime)= '2022' and LOCATION_address_1 LIKE '%6210 GLENWAY%')
    or LOCATION_address_1  like '%480 WILEY%'
```

i.e. either 2022 *and* GLENWAY, or WILEY (no matter which year.)

But you want

```
where year(created_datetime)= '2022'
  and (LOCATION_address_1 LIKE '%6210 GLENWAY%'
    or LOCATION_address_1  like '%480 WILEY%')
```

I.e. the year must be 2022, and the address LIKE *one of* GLENWAY or WILEY or etc